# Why does updating to the latest Gradle plugin produce 'Multiple dex files define' issue

Tags: android, gradle

I have and android library project, which has one subproject depending on another. Currently, when building, this works fine as expected. The `build.gradle` file has the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
```

However, if I change this to have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'`, then it gives be this error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/mycompany/android/SomeClass;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

If I change it back to `0.11.+` then it builds again. What is causing this, and how do I resolve this without making it into a new project?

Answer (score 0):

Check libs folder in your subproject for library named same as the project it is depending on, if you find it, delete it from your project structure(you can keep it on disc). I had same error with new gradle plugin and I found out that this was causing it.

Comment: Neither of the subprojects have a 'libs' folder - nor the parent.